# ng-submitted class is not added on sub form

Tags: angularjs

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stevemao/zc6htcob/

a class `ng-submitted` should be added on the `ng-form` directive when hitting the Submit button. What am I missing?

Comment: also `subForm.$submitted` is `false` on the subForm after the parent form is submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take a look at this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10071

It is a known issue and you can find several workarounds there.

Comment: Hm... It's weird I do have a project that works properly.

Comment: My bad... that project was using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818757/set-angularjs-nested-forms-to-submitted